# How to classify records based don running difference?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out how to find beginning of each sequence of records, where sequence stars when the time difference between records that belong to the same category is greater for example 5 minuntes.

For example, I have a table like:

| field1 | field2 | date | category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | abc | 2021-05-05 16:11:00 | 1 |
| 13 | abc | 2021-05-05 16:11:35 | 1 |
| 20 | eee | 2021-05-05 18:22:22 | 2 |
| 21 | aaa | 2021-05-05 20:00:00 | 1 |
| 28 | www | 2021-05-05 21:22:22 | 1 |
| 27 | ddd | 2021-05-05 21:23:33 | 1 |

which is sorted by date in ascending order. I would like to mark beginning of each sequence for category 1, so the expected result would be:

| field1 | field2 | date | category | result | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | abc | 2021-05-05 16:11:00 | 1 | 1 | Session starts |
| 13 | abc | 2021-05-05 16:11:35 | 1 | 0 |  |
| 20 | eee | 2021-05-05 18:22:22 | 2 | 0 |  |
| 21 | aaa | 2021-05-05 20:00:00 | 1 | 1 | Session starts |
| 28 | www | 2021-05-05 21:22:22 | 1 | 1 | Session starts |
| 27 | ddd | 2021-05-05 21:23:33 | 1 | 0 |  |

The first problem that I am facing with is because there are two categories. So far I found time difference in minutes between consecutive rows:

```
WITH data as (
SELECT 
    table1.field1, 
    table1.field2, 
    table1.date, 
    table1.category 
FROM table1
)

SELECT *, 
    @diff:= TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, @prev_date, data.date) AS diff,
    @prev_date:= data.date as dummy
FROM data
```

so, I get:

| field1 | field2 | date | category | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 14 | abc | 2021-05-05 16:11:00 | 1 | -312 |
| 13 | abc | 2021-05-05 16:11:35 | 1 | 0 |
| 20 | eee | 2021-05-05 18:22:22 | 2 | 130 |
| 21 | aaa | 2021-05-05 20:00:00 | 1 | 97 |
| 28 | www | 2021-05-05 21:22:22 | 1 | 82 |
| 27 | ddd | 2021-05-05 21:23:33 | 1 | 1 |

but, I do not know how to create beginning of sequences. Acceptetble solution is also if category 2 'resets' session that belong to category 1. So, after every record that has category 2, a new sequence starts for category 1, regardless of previous timestamp.

Here is the dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `field1` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `field2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `table1` 
(`field1`, `field2`, `date`, `category`) 
VALUES
(14, 'abc', '2021-05-05 16:11:00', '1'),
(13, 'abc', '2021-05-05 16:11:35', '1'),
(20, 'eee', '2021-05-05 18:22:22', '2'),
(21, 'aaa', '2021-05-05 20:00:00', '1'),
(28, 'www', '2021-05-05 21:22:22', '1'),
(27, 'ddd', '2021-05-05 21:23:33', '1');
```

and the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7e4aa47e2096692f151a2a874670e582) of same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `lag()` window function let you access the "previous" record so that you can check the time difference.

```
SELECT field1,
       field2,
       date,
       category,
       category = 1
       AND (lag(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) IS NULL
             OR timestampdiff(MINUTE, lag(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), date) > 5) result,
       CASE
         WHEN category = 1
              AND (lag(date) OVER (ORDER BY date) IS NULL
                    OR timestampdiff(MINUTE, lag(date) OVER (ORDER BY date), date) > 5) THEN
           'Session starts'
       END comment
       FROM table1
       ORDER BY date;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0368f1a9525f12ee8f81b2d71e89b69c)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, LAG(`date`) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY `date`), `date`) < 300
            THEN 0
            ELSE 1
            END result,
       CASE WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(second, LAG(`date`) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY `date`), `date`) < 300
            THEN ''
            ELSE 'Session starts'
            END Comment
FROM table1
ORDER BY `date`
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b0d75c7a448201580c53605d439c56d3